# Load native library twice

Tags: android, android-ndk, native, native-code

I use [RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) on Android to download a stream. If I run the library the first time everything works fine. On second time the app doesn't initiate the RTMP download :/

I searched the last three days and know that I can't load a native library twice or just unload it and that I have three options to handle my problem:

1. Using a custom class loader (after System.gc() library was still loaded)
2. Running a service in its own process (it didn't work. The library was still loaded after killing the service).
3. Write a native library that loads the RTMP library via `dlopen` and closes it via `dlclose`.

I don't know any further option :/ I even don't know how to write the native library to load other library :/

I used this RTMP dump: https://github.com/eschriek/rtmpdump-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found found a way to do it :) Maybe it is not a beautiful one, but it works fine:

1. Create a service:

   ```
   import android.app.Service;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.AsyncTask;
   import android.os.IBinder;

   public class rtmpdumpService extends Service {

       @Override
       public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
           super.onStart(intent, startId);
           config = this;
           String extras = "";
           if(intent != null){

               //Get needed information
               extras = intent.getExtras().getString("rtmp");
           }
           else {
               this.stopSelf();
           }
           doWork(extras);
       }

       @Override
       public void onDestroy() {
           super.onDestroy();
       }

       public void doWork(String rtmp){
           //Do work here: for example rtmpdump
           Rtmpdump dump = new Rtmpdump();
           dump.parseString(params[0]);
           System.exit(0);
           this.stopSelf();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register in AndroidManifest as service with these attributes

   ```
   android:name=".rtmpdumpService"
   android:exported="false"
   android:process=":rtmp"
   ```
3. Start service:

   ```
   Intent rtmpdumpIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), rtmpdumpService.class);
               eSendIntent.putExtra("rtmp", "RTMP CODE");
               startService(rtmpdumpIntent);
   ```

Sometimes you have to wait until it finishes:

After the Service is started (startService(rtmpdumpIntent):

```
do {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //Log
    }
} while( isServiceRunning(rtmpdumpService.class) == true);
```

isServiceRunning function:

```
    private boolean isServiceRunning(Class cl) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (cl.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```